# Vega embed not rendering graph

Tags: vega, vega-lite, vegasjs

I am trying to reproduce this tutorial 
https://nyurik.github.io/Vega-Trends-Graph-for-Kibana/

While spec is rendering in the kibana-vega plugin (kibana version 6.3.0), the exact same sepc doesn't render any visualisation in the vega online editor.
vega embed isn't raising any errors, and data viewer looks like data is prcoessed correctly. 
[vega embed online editor with spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgGY6ABjoArWNwB2kADTgoAE3R5MOANqqIoCEajz0qZNigV0AG1bJYy-UcjW7DyGF3BIAa2QAngD66LBBsHgATozy1NiQAEwSAIwAHAC0EhnJAKwAKskAbFgJCVgSUhUSAFrKfoHYuaIALKI5KUlVSpBq3PBB8Nys8njYEgC+Sj7+waHhUTFxWIkpGVnpuQXFCaLllRW13TONOS1tq1US3b39g8OjWKKT04EhYRHRsfFJaZnZ+UUSs09pIDnVjlgmq12glmpdrn0BkMRo1ks96rN3gsvssfmt-lsSjkQVVDhiTmd2qJLlceoi7iisABOdEzN7zT5LFa-dabQEJYoVUE1cENSGnaESUSFeF027Ih7JCZTDHsj6Lb6rP4bAHbADsJLBRzFUPOzU6FQR8vu2FSrNec3VOO5+J1hISqUNIuNAQpkuaqVlNyRNqwOXtmI5GtxWt5upKTK9ZIhpvaOThXTlIcZzQjauxXLx2r5xWpSdFvvFlIkMqD9IV2D1ecdBc1PIJgNEyXLPr950KtctWYZDztKrZLc5bddJceZSFpIrffaeottODI9RzaxU5j7bdnd2C6N5Krkr1gczG4bWEK26jzqLccJLR7p9TWQzQ+vobv44dO7Ri6xbxm0b4phK5xMjSVrZqO95OoWsYdqWgr7N676Qe0TKDuu9ahrm-6Roh04gS+BrHhhEGUkqa6wZukIJAhrZ7jOoGepRyYmlhSqXt++GMmOLzESxwHPp2iacUuZ5tMkyRfnh1qCcxu5iShWBwuB3E0WuilwY2KlAU+6nNN2Um9jJOTJAKdZKQ8LIALoqMYECQFE6DyLAABm3CRKglh6C5RiGEFLh4AEhAWDgkAAO4xL0MVOKFLjcMQAXOMlkCRNwMVBPIrCoOwyCRJAGUuU5ZXGJAoTpclVXZbl+WFcVpV1WADmVWAkydSFmXhZFliQD5fmsDYmDOXVkDIAAHoQJXRV5NjcL5AAUK0aHgBV0A1eUFUVkQbAAlKQSqHUlk01dF1DZawhCtaF3XJb1oVuRFUVQOg1DXcIeAWBNmXXUMhDsJWYCBW1UCA7d93JRVbWQKlji6J1VWwAVMOhXDk1eYwyA2GoSNgyjLg-iixNY5ll1ExDUCbuTnXjGVHXGI9wVlZApjmINkQOKNeCOP9LhuPYhPg0FwCM0FFNhZEHneb5-nI09xOvQNC0K6N40qzNc2DRt6ArQA5MLDiG4dOgSA5dCboLQXVYTkBjREGMs7bbPw-171DRrY3nZlOvzeomgG8btgi2bOjJFbNsq1TkBzcgFAu0YrPiyrnuDcNqCa37L0B3rmhbU7eAAHwbVtCdJ27VVx9DDPV2Az12xn6sjb7Deufn0Xl6gdDFwAPD3dCV7ndtxwlij1z16dvZnPta-DXdQIwXnrYXvfFwAvJvVxgCva+bb3lfb1cVxHUoYAH0XoR4OkQ+V8dQ-F2dHcfQ7kWRPAyAjAAwogHnUAsFPZWHtZ6t2zu3bWs1A6QH3kPW6ShDZYEOobJQcD150AnogrARtEHpDNi-WODtYABEKtwGwycICS3Ks4ahWNIAYEiL4UWzgm5QBbuwmaow3ZDWyorRunUejB25rzGw-Nk6pxcN-QYah3psNcrdDacj05cMsPIlykBYCMGoKYCh3cMEkLITYMAABqMAhtzGmLAE-G+ViLFGzMVnTQV8j7FS-r-f+sRkAX0NiYugyQACkZs7EoMoSnV+Q1GA2D0QImmmjtG6MGugw+dAEHmIAMQVC8l5CoqC96ryHlgjJ2TLh5MNpkqo2SCFhKoRE2wCS1HE1cibQa7jfolWJpIu27BQh4xiMouJLToqoEYGoNQNggFtS6Ro6a8BGlxK0To2wg04pqBYKQBINSuoRICHMnA6jUYJOWdFFA2j8AbK2dMqqPkRgAGVGAAC8BkQ3iUsmJDCYgrVWespUF9TnUHwMdZIdBRCXIZmVahVDVAdXGEAA)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.0.json",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "values",
      "values" : [{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:22:00.000Z","key":1534350120000,"doc_count":0},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:23:00.000Z","key":1534350180000,"doc_count":3},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:24:00.000Z","key":1534350240000,"doc_count":11},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:25:00.000Z","key":1534350300000,"doc_count":9},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:26:00.000Z","key":1534350360000,"doc_count":10},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:27:00.000Z","key":1534350420000,"doc_count":8},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:28:00.000Z","key":1534350480000,"doc_count":5},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:29:00.000Z","key":1534350540000,"doc_count":4},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:30:00.000Z","key":1534350600000,"doc_count":7},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:31:00.000Z","key":1534350660000,"doc_count":8},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:32:00.000Z","key":1534350720000,"doc_count":11},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:33:00.000Z","key":1534350780000,"doc_count":6},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:34:00.000Z","key":1534350840000,"doc_count":6},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:35:00.000Z","key":1534350900000,"doc_count":8},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:36:00.000Z","key":1534350960000,"doc_count":4},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:37:00.000Z","key":1534351020000,"doc_count":12},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:38:00.000Z","key":1534351080000,"doc_count":8},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:39:00.000Z","key":1534351140000,"doc_count":8},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:40:00.000Z","key":1534351200000,"doc_count":7},{"key_as_string":"2018-08-15T16:41:00.000Z","key":1534351260000,"doc_count":9}],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "window",
          "ops": [
            "row_number"
          ],
          "as": [
            "row_number"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "floor((datum.row_number-1)/10)",
          "as": "group"
        },
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": [
            "group"
          ],
          "ops": [
            "sum"
          ],
          "fields": [
            "doc_count"
          ],
          "as": [
            "count"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "results",
      "values": [
        {}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "data('values')[0].count",
          "as": "last"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "data('values')[1].count",
          "as": "prev"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.last>datum.prev",
          "as": "up"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "datum.last<datum.prev",
          "as": "down"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "if(datum.last==0, if(datum.prev==0,0,-1), (datum.last-datum.prev)/datum.last)",
          "as": "percentChange"
        },
        {
          "type": "formula",
          "expr": "if(datum.up,':)',if(datum.down,':(','-'))",
          "as": "symbol"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {
        "data": "results"
      },
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "text": {
            "signal": "datum.symbol + ' ' + datum.last + ' ('+ format(datum.percentChange, '+.1%') + ')'"
          },
          "fill": {
            "signal": "if(datum.up, '#00ff00', if(datum.down, '#ff0000', '#0000ff'))"
          },
          "align": {
            "value": "center"
          },
          "baseline": {
            "value": "middle"
          },
          "xc": {
            "signal": "width/2"
          },
          "yc": {
            "signal": "height/2"
          },
          "fontSize": {
            "signal": "min(width/10, height)/1.3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The editor uses Vega 4 right now but your spec is Vega 3. I haven't looked at what the exact problem is but this may be the problem.

Comment: Ahh, if you set width and height, it works.